# How to simulate Explode() function with a MySQL view or procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, list, view, explode

I have a MySQL TABLE where data look like this

```
Struct : 
Id | Field N°1 

Data : 
1 | "File1.doc, File1.xls, File1.pdf"
2 | "File2.doc, File2.xls, File2.pdf"
```

What i would like to get thanks to a MySQL VIEW :

```
1 | "File1.doc"
1 | "File2.xls"
1 | "File1.pdf"
2 | "File2.doc"
2 | "File1.xls"
2 | "File2.pdf"
```

Does someone has any idea ? I do not want to do it throw a Php script, i need to do it in SQL.

Comment: Can you specify the language, please? Also add it as a tag.

Comment: Normalize your data model. You shouldn't be storing multiple values in a single column

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = <<<STR
1 | "File1.doc, File1.xls, File1.pdf"
2 | "File2.doc, File2.xls, File2.pdf"
STR;

$rows = explode("\n", $data);

$result = array();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $num = $row[0];
    $str = substr($row, 5, strlen($row) - 6);
    $files = explode(', ', $str);
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $result[] = $num.' | "'.$file.'"';
    }
}

foreach ($result as $file)
{
    echo '<p>'.$file.'</p>';
}
?>
```

Result will be:

```
1 | "File1.doc"

1 | "File1.xls"

1 | "File1.pdf"

2 | "File2.doc"

2 | "File2.xls"

2 | "File2.pdf"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not specify it but my data are in a MySql TABLE and I would like to get the result throw a MySql VIEW, not thanks to a php script.

Comment: It makes some difference :)